# How to add a relationship in google analytics reports views?

Tags: views, google-analytics

So I created a custom module and added a .inc file. Inside that file I've defined a hook_views_data() in which I have defined content entity relationship so that it supports GA reports.

Code in .inc file

```
function custom_module_views_data() {
  $data = [];
    
  // Define the relationship to the content entity.
  $data['google_analytics_reports']['content'] = [
    'title' => t('Content'),
    'help' => t('Relate the Google Analytics Reports to the associated content.'),
    'relationship' => [
      'title' => t('Content'),
      'help' => t('Relate the Google Analytics Reports to the associated content.'),
      'base' => 'node_field_data',
      'base field' => 'nid',
      'field' => 'google_analytics_reports_nid',
      'id' => 'standard',
      'label' => t('Content'),
    ],
  ];
  return $data;
}
```

But now when I add the content relationship and also the fields in error logs it's showing

> Error: Call to undefined method
> Drupal\google_analytics_reports\Plugin\views\query\GoogleAnalyticsQuery::addRelationship()
> in
> Drupal\views\Plugin\views\relationship\RelationshipPluginBase->query()

What exactly I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is reported as a change request on the module: https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports/issues/3367021. If there is a more specific question on a particular aspect of authoring that change, that could be answerable here.

Comment: I have reformed my question hope this helps,